# Cannot install brew on Mojave with Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, homebrew, macos-mojave

I can not install any brew packages on my mac with the following error info.

**Installed on my Mac:**

- macOS 10.14 Beta (18A293u)
- Xcode 9.3 (9E145)
- Xcode 10.0 beta (10L176w)

Type in `brew install xxx`. The output is:

```
Error: Your Xcode (9.3) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 10.0 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Mojave.
Install the Command Line Tools:
xcode-select --install
```

But as I type in `xcode-select --install`, it says it is not available
[Xcode select install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBB2u.png)

Paths of two versions of Xcode on my Mac:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app
/Applications/Xcode.app
```

And my config output:
**xcode-select -p**

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

**brew config**

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.6.7
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 22e9fd772926e389e264cfb328c3d810b06759f9
Last commit: 5 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 854bb90b366169915849fc9a83e941b8883cea1f
Core tap last commit: 6 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
CPU: octa-core 64-bit haswell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.6 =>./System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 9.1 build 902
Git: 2.15.1 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 1.8.0_131
macOS: 10.14-x86_64
CLT: N/A
Xcode: 9.3
XQuartz: N/A
```

Comment: Upvoted because so well asked, but also voted to close because this should have been asked on AskDifferent or SuperUser.

Comment: Had this same issue earlier today. Resolved by downloading CL Tools from developer.apple.com, and running both CLTools_SDK and CLTools_Executables.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to install both "**Xcode 10.0 Beta**" from https://developer.apple.com/download/ **AND** "**Command Line Tools (macOS 10.14) for Xcode 10 Beta**" from

https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.dmg

Update contributed by other comments, after you installed "Command Line Tools", you will also need to execute the following command in your terminal.

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Comment: I am using Xcode 10.0 beta 3 (on macOS 10.14) and there is no command line tools available for beta 3 version.

Answer (score 20):

Beginning in 10.14, a new step is required to create the header files in /usr/include:

Install `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`

Source: [The Xcode 10 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes)

Comment: That's it. Cheers

Answer (score 9):

After installing CLT, you can ask CLT to add header files to `/usr/include`, then homebrew will appropriate detect the Command Line Tools.

```
installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Answer (score 3):

After installing **Xcode 10 Beta** and **Command Line Tools (macOS 10.14) for Xcode 10 Beta**, I also changed the path for **xcode-select** to use the newly installed command line tools with:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 1):

At this time, Brew is not supporting macOS Mojave Beta.

(Type `brew doctor` to confirm that they are not accepting issues for Mojave yet)

See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327458/install-homebrew-packages-on-macos-mojave-beta

See: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/4295

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install Homebrew on Mojave by manually downloading the command line tools here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Modify the Homebrew install script here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install

By replacing:

```
def should_install_command_line_tools?
  return false if force_curl?
  return false if macos_version < "10.9"
  !File.exist?("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git") ||
  !File.exist?("/usr/include/iconv.h")
end
```

With this:

```
def should_install_command_line_tools?
  return true
end
```

Then just execute the script.

This is a little hacky, but it worked for me and could help someone out in the beta period.

Comment: I did not try the hacking way, but installing CLTools works.Thanks very much. Unfortunately, I still failed in installing my brew package, like `brew install octave`. It says     `Error: You are using macOS 10.14.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.`

Comment: This answer pointed me in the correct direction, but, having manually installed Xcode Beta 2 and the associated command line tools, I updated the code block above to `return false` NOT `return true` (you've already installed command line tools, so brew should not). I was then able to install homebrew as expected and installing packages with brew is also working correctly

Comment: You can avoid modifying the script by installing /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14. pkg

Answer (score -1):

confirm that Command Line Tools for 10.14 won't create `/usr/include/` folder that makes brew install script insist to re-download and install CL.

download the script, and manual removing checking works fine. (be aware it should be **false** instead of **true**.

```
def should_install_command_line_tools?
  return **false**
end
```

Comment: You can create the headers in /usr/include by installing /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.
pkg

Comment: yes we also found the same solution yesterday. thanks @craig65535