# macOS 10.14(beta) How to install Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10_Beta

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line-tool, xcode10, macos-mojave

As the Title of my question, I don't know how to install the Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10_Beta for my mac, please help.

What I did:

1. run command "brew install carthage" to install the Carthage, get errors:

> Error: Your Xcode (9.4.1) is too outdated.
>       Please update to Xcode 10.0 (or delete it).
>       Xcode can be updated from
>         https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

2. run command "xcode-select --install" in Terminal as [the second answer from @Dev](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327458/install-homebrew-packages-on-macos-mojave-beta), but I still get the same errors after "brew install carthage";

[image: error]

3. download the .dmg file from [Apple site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/), I got too many tools after I opened it:

[image: tools]

I've tried install the two .pkg which marked with red rectangle in the attached image, but the error still coming.

Environment:

```
macOS 10.14 Beta
Xcode(Installed 2 versions on the Mac): 
10 (Beta), 
9.4.1
```

Comment: Installing XCode 10 beta as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50791809/1330283 worked for me.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It looks like you have two versions of the xcode installed on your machine.
First select the latest version of the xcode by running this command:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch <path/to/>Xcode.app
```

Once this is done, install the required command line tools but running this command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, the command "sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app" looks working for me.

Comment: BTW, I still do not know how to install the command line tool from Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10_Beta.dmg

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm on Mojave. Tried also to uninstall Xcode 10 and delete to re install the toolchain. nothing worked. still having the same error message. Any idea?

Comment: For the Mojave OS, try installing the command line tools downloaded from Apple developer program site.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Mojave public beta either.

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

1. Download "Xcode 10.0 Beta" from https://developer.apple.com/download/
2. Unzip it and move it to `/Applications`
3. Download "Command Line Tools (macOS 10.14) for Xcode 10 Beta" from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
4. Run the installer for "Command Line Tools"
5. Launch the `Xcode-beta` application and wait for it to install necessary packages when it prompts it at launch
6. Run this from the command line `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/`

Now `brew update` should work again.

Comment: Just for clarification, did these steps work for you on High Sierra or were you running the beta of Mojave?

Comment: This was AFTER upgrading from High Sierra to Mojave Beta.

Answer (score 13):

This fixed things for me, on a fresh 10.14 Beta 3 install.

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Comment: installing Xcode 10.0 beta, and performing the above steps from Ev Haus, xcode-select ---switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/ and this step worked  this is good, please do this before attempting to install Homebrew from the brew install script.

Comment: Tried this but it breaks the system update next time. Had to reinstall old xcode to fix that.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying and failing to `pip install libsass` for python. After running this command, the build succeeded.

Answer (score 8):

Following worked for me:

After you updated to **Mojave 10.14**
Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
search for **"command line"** then

download "**Command line tool for MacOS 10.14**"

Once dmg is downloaded install the package.

Verify package installation
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with Beta 3 and Homebrew. I literally spent 2 hours trying everything listed here to no avail. I was only able to make it work by installing Beta 2, installing Homebrew and then updating to Beta 3.

[Homebrew and Beta 3 - Command Line Tools](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/105556)

Comment: Can you list more steps?

Comment: I literally installed a fresh Beta 2, installed Homebrew, and THEN updated to Beta 3.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal run the command:

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app`

***note:** `xcode-select --install` command is deprecated, but the command line tools should installed already.*

Comment: @whenov not sure, but that’s the message you get. I think it’s related to how system software updates are now managed by the system and not the App Store (including command line tools)

Comment: On my newly-updated Mojave system, after I launched XCode and let it update, then `xcode-select --install` and it worked.